# Raw JS removing of a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a toggle action but with raw JS. So instead of using toggle class I must add and remove each part.

When the user clicks a radio button, one div gets class `enabled` and the other gets class `disabled` which controls my styling (to grey the area out)

[JS Fiddle showing the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/argokLfp/2/)

I am using the following for this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('justfull');
d.className = d.className + " enabled";
```

and then giving the other div `disabled`

```
var other = document.getElementById('firstandlast');
other.className = other.className + " disabled";
```

But I am stuck when it comes to removing the class if it's previously been added. As obviously the user can toggle between the two radio buttons. I need to add the `enabled` class to my new div but I also need to check to see if there was previously a `disabled` class added to it and if so, remove it.

So I am using the following code:

```
var oldclass="disabled"; 
d.className=d.className.replace(oldclass,"");
```

But this doesn't seem to work as the classname just adds and adds until I have something like this:

```
<div id="justfull" class="  enabled  enabled  enabled disabled">
```

**How would I properly both add the `enabled` class and check for a removal of the other?** Essentially a toggle class but in raw JS.

Comment: You can toggle classes with `Element.classList` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList - if you're worried about browser compatibility, it can easily be polyfilled

Comment: Why not actually use the `disabled` attribute of the checkbox input? Then, you can style the spans like: `input + span {}` and `input[disabled] + span {}`

Comment: Instead of checking or replacing `disabled` class, why don't you just set the class name to `enabled` or `disabled` like `d.className = "enabled";` or `other.className = "disabled";`?

Comment: the order of the operations might be wrong, but you will get the point... http://jsfiddle.net/sq6r4xc8/